# how to take a problematic pod offline to troubleshoot

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

HI I know there's a way i can pull out a problematic node out of loadbalancer to troubleshoot. But how can i pull a pod out of service to troubleshoot. What tools or command can do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in Oreilly's "Kubernetes recipes: Maintenance and troubleshooting" [page here](https://www.oreilly.com/ideas/kubernetes-recipes-maintenance-and-troubleshooting)

> **Removing a Pod from a Service**
>
> ***Problem***
>
> You have a well-defined service (see not available) backed by several
>   pods. But one of the pods is misbehaving, and you would like to take
>   it out of the list of endpoints to examine it at a later time.
>
> ***Solution***
>
> Relabel the pod using the --overwrite option—this will allow you to
>   change the value of the run label on the pod. By overwriting this
>   label, you can ensure that it will not be selected by the service
>   selector (not available) and will be removed from the list of
>   endpoints. At the same time, the replica set watching over your pods
>   will see that a pod has disappeared and will start a new replica.
>
> To see this in action, start with a straightforward deployment
>   generated with kubectl run (see not available):

For commands, check the recipes page mentioned above. There is also a section talking about "Debugging Pods" which will be helpful

Answer (score 5):

Change its labels so they no longer matches the `selector:` in the `Service`; we used to do that all the time. You can even put it back into rotation if you want to test a hypothesis. I don't recall exactly how quickly it takes effect, but I would guess "real quick" is a good approximation. :-)

```shell
## for example:
$ kubectl label pod $the_pod -app.kubernetes.io/name
## or, change it to non-matching
$ kubectl label pod $the_pod app.kubernetes.io/name=i-am-debugging-this-pod
```